# AG Grid change detection for the whole grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

The team is working with Angular AG-Grid. The grid itself has 52 columns with up to 40,000 rows.

We are supposed to create some kind of change detection so that the user will be notified about having unsaved changes (by that I mean - didn't hit the 'Save to the database' button) when trying to hit F5/refresh button or closing the app completely.
I couldn't find anything in the AG-Grid documentation that would allow us to compare initial state of the grid when the data was first loaded to the changes that the user made.
We are using @HostListener elsewhere for the 'window:beforeunload' event but that is the next step. First, I'd like to find out how to handle change detection in such a big grid.

Comment: if I were you, I'd try your strategy in a smaller set first; then check pagination before implementation

Comment: Unfortunately, the business doesn't want pagination :) Problem was we kept gridOptions object in a separate file. That was causing an issue because we couldn't find a good reference to that 'export const gridOptions = {} '. I moved it into the grid component and works fine now:)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to `JSON.stringify` your original data and compared it to the stringified data from the table, and see if they match or not. Even with 52 columns and up to 40,000 rows, this should be too much of an intensive operation.

Here is a simple function that would check this for you:

```
  checkChanges() {

    console.log('data changed: ');
    console.log(
      JSON.stringify(this.rowData) != JSON.stringify(this.originalData)
    );
  }
```

You can use the following function in the `gridReady` callback to get the row data since you say you don't have access to it:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    const api = params.api;
    this.rowsToDisplay = params.api.getModel().rowsToDisplay.map((x) => x.data);
    this.originalData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rowData));
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-jslfey?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: The problem was I didn't have access to 'this.rowData' because gridOptions object was kept in a separate file as 'export const gridOptions = {} '. I moved it inside the grid component and I can use any variables from within that component in the gridOptions object.

Comment: See my updated answer, you can get he row data via the api.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the task by setting some flag in the app state, e.g `gridDirty: boolean`. And then listening grid event `cellValueChanged`, set the flag. When Save button hit and data is saved — reset the flag.